# YiiStrap vs YiiWheels - yii framework and twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

What is the difference between them? Pros and cons? In getyiistrap.com Chris states: 2amigOS! also maintain their own extension library called YiiWheels that includes many more widgets. So is YiiWheels better in any way?

Comment: if it is of any help, you would get better answers to this on the official forum for Yii

Answer (score 2):

You can use YiiStrap or both.
"YiiWheels is an Extension Library for Yiistrap" © http://yiiwheels.2amigos.us/

So this is kinda strange question like "what the difference between Chrome and ChromeAdBlock?" :D